Github actions env is not the same as script's env
I have a workflow like this:
name: System Test

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - test

jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Testing Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: setting env
        env:
          ert: hola
        run: |
          echo "test: $ert"
          echo "ert=hola" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          env

      - name: System testing (build + execution)
        run: |
          ls
          export ert=hola
          chmod +x testing.sh
          sudo ./testing.sh

I tried all the options, but no one gave me the result I want.
In the testing.sh script, it appears only an env command, and in the 'setting env' step, it has another env command. The problem is that in the 'setting env' step, the env command shows me ert=hola, but in the script, it doesn't. Why the variable is not set as an environment variable?

There were a few subtle issues:
1. Environment Variable Case Sensitivity

ert: hola (lowercase) in the env: block
echo "ert=hola" >> $GITHUB_ENV (lowercase)

2. Inconsistent Variable Setting

You used both env: block and export
The export ert=hola in the script step was local to that step only.

The corrected version will be like this: Also, read more about the environment scope in workflow, job, and step level.
name: System Test
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - test
jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Testing Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Setting Environment Variables
        run: |
          echo "ERT=hola" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - name: Verify Environment Variables
        run: |
          echo "Environment variable: $ERT"
          env | grep ERT
      
      - name: System testing (build + execution)
        run: |
          echo "In testing script: $ERT"
          chmod +x testing.sh
          ./testing.sh

testing.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "ERT in script: $ERT"
env | grep ERT

How I triggered it:
gh api repos/myusername/mygithubrepo/dispatches --field event_type=test

Output:


I mean, your answer is correct and helps me to realize that the problem was the 'sudo' command I put for the script execution

@ATLAS glad it helps you somehow
